# Python Match Group

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

I'm having trouble creating a match group to extract two values from a string using python

Here's my input:

```
# SomeKey: Value Is A String
```

And I'd like to be able to extract `SomeKey` and `Value Is A String` using a python match group / regex statement. Here's what I have so far

```
import re
line = "# SomeKey: Value Is A String"
mg = re.match(r"# <key>: <value>", line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide the string you're matching:

```
import re
line = "# SomeKey: Value Is A String"
mg = re.match(r"# ([^:]+): (.*)", line)

>>> print mg.group(1)
SomeKey
>>> print mg.group(2)
Value Is A String
```

Or to automatically get a tuple of key and value, you can do:

```
import re
line = "# SomeKey: Value Is A String"
mg = re.findall(r"# ([^:]+): (.*)", line)

>>> print mg
[('SomeKey', 'Value Is A String')]
```

[**DEMO**](http://repl.it/SSD)

For names, you would do:

```
mg = re.match(r"# (?P<key>[^:]+): (?P<value>.*)", line)
print mg.group('key')
```

[**DEMO**](http://repl.it/SSE)

Comment: I mistyped my question. Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: how can I use the named group?

Comment: its something like (<name>) I believe

Comment: @JonMorehouse, What do you mean. Meanwhile, I have updated my answer yet again

Comment: @JonMorehouse, Answer updated to include named groups.

Comment: this is what I meant: `mg = re.match(r"# (?P<label>[^:]+): (?P<value>.*)", line)`

Answer (score 0):

Unless your real use-case is way more complicated, you can directly unpack the values into the corresponding variables by using `findall` like this:

```
import re
line = "# SomeKey: Value Is A String"
key, val = re.findall(r"# (.*?): (.*)$", line)[0]
# (key, val) == ('SomeKey', 'Value Is A String')
```